# Is it possible to have more than one string resource file in Android?

Tags: android, xml, string, resources

I have my primary string resource file for android, and it is quite full (with no end in sight). So, I was hoping to do some house cleaning and move some string into their own resource file. Is this possible?

I know that one can have something like `string-en` or `string-de`, but is it possible to maybe have a resource file such as `string-errors`?

Comment: Alreday answered here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13922522/are-there-any-side-effects-of-using-multiple-string-xml-files

Comment: @SultanMirza My question was asked first... almost 5 years ago.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Apparently so. I just took a small app of mine, created a new XML file, `values/labels.xml`, and moved some of my string resources from `values/strings.xml` into it. I made no other changes to the app; it still worked fine.

Comment: As long as the strings in the new file are still defined using the <string> xml tags, you can have as many resource files as you want.  You still reference them in the same way as before, with `R.string.string_name`

Comment: Yup, I made no other changes, so it still had to be referenced the same way. Thanks to theisenp for clarifying.