# Are there any side-effects of using multiple string.xml files?

Tags: android, string, android-xml

I am currently creating an application that have some strings (>300 for now) and I have some problems to quickly find a string  with so many of them.
So I was considering the possibility of using several `string.xml` files instead of only one (string_menu, string_activity1, ...).

Is there any side-effect with this practice? Is it a bad or a good practice?

I ask this because it seems that no many people on the net are using this possibility.
So maybe there is some problem with it?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#String) you can use whatever filename you want:

> The filename is arbitrary. The <string> element's name will be used as the resource ID.

Comment: i am currently talking about the file name, the string.xml file

Comment: in fact my question is : is there any side-effect ?

Comment: There are no side-effects. You can access all strings in the same way: `R.string.textname`

Comment: Apparently the resource compiler looks for and identifies all string resources, regardless of file name.  You can partition your strings into multiple files and keep the references as R.string...

Answer (score 15):

There may be negligible side effects in performance, you can add as much as you can. I have 3 activity files **MainActivity**, **PhotoActivity**, **UserActivity**, create a common strings.xml file and other activity related files.

```
-strings.xml                    -> create common string values here.
  --strings_main.xml            -> create main activity specific string values here.
  --strings_photo.xml           -> ...
  --strings_user.xml            -> ... etc etc
```

Hope this is helpful. Thanks!