# Creating multiple APKs with different source code

Tags: java, android, maven, jenkins

I use Jenkins to build my Android project, which currently just outputs one APK file.

I'd like to be able to output two APK files with, say, two different names (e.g., `android-app-A.apk` and `android-app-B.apk`).

In addition, I need a value in my source code to change between the `A` and `B` APK. In particular, its a `String` variable.

For example, for `android-app-A`, the `String` value should be **foo**. And for `android-app-B`, it should be **bar**. So if the app just displayed the `String` value, it would read **foo** when the person ran the `android-app-A.apk` and **bar** when the user ran `android-app-B.apk`

If it helps, I'm also using Maven to manage my Android project dependencies.

Is there any way to make this happen?

I've looked at [Maven Profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) and skimmed a little of Android Developer's page on [Maintaining Multiple APKs](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-apks/index.html) but I'm not sure what is the best approach and whether this is even possible.

Answer (score 1):

Maven is probably not the best build tool to achieve this. I strongly suggest you to use [gradle](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system) as it contains a built-in feature : the `productFlavor` allowing you to do exactly what you need.

Comment: I can't use Gradle since my project and build environment is heavily dependant on Maven.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by heavily... but you can use maven dependencies resolution with gradle and gradle integrates very well with jenkins

Answer (score 0):

Multiple APK names:
The name of the MainActivity is used for the name of a APK. It is stated in the **AndroidManifest.xml** with the `android:label` tag and usually references the `app_name` `String` in the **String.xml** in the Folder **values** of your project. So simple change this `String` before exporting the second APK.

For your second approach:
Why you don't change the String value itself if it is only one?
In the case that there are more different take the use of multiple String Manifests and comment the other out. How to use multiple String.xml was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13922522/multiple-string-xml-files).

Comment: How do you integrate this in a CI build system ?